# Question about APS Ethics Case Study

Tags: ethics

The [American Physical Society *Ethics Case Studies*](https://www.aps.org/programs/education/ethics/upload/Ethics-Case-Studies-Student-Edition.pdf) presents the following case study:

> You are a faculty mentor for a graduate student in your department. The student is taking some classes in another department that requires written essays. He asks you to read his essay before he submits it. 
>   You routinely google his work and discover that large parts have been lifted, verbatim, from the web with no quotation marks or citations.
>
> 1. What should you do?
> 2. Is there a way to monitor this student’s future behavior without irreparably damaging his career?

Unlike many of the scenarios, this one has no discussion. What are the answers to the questions?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - Personally, I'm on the fence here. On the one hand, this question sure looks like homework. On the other hand, it's very on-topic for this site. It [doesn't look like we've discussed](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework+questions+is%3Aquestion) homework questions being posted to the site on Meta yet. [I just posted this question for discussion](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/3264/73), feel free to discuss there.

Comment: @StrongBad this question does in fact have a discussion on the next page in the PDF. Here it is [on the APS website](http://www.aps.org/programs/education/ethics/undergraduate/plagarism-discussion.cfm)

Comment: @ff524 while I tried... I guess the APS answer would be a good answer to this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hypothetical of unclear motivation, copied from another website.

Comment: Even if this question is on-topic, it (IMHO) deserves a downvote due to lack of effort.

Answer (score 2):

"Your paper looks like it has some citation problems.  Do you have any questions about when and how you should cite the work of others?"  Provide help if asked.  (There's a *lot* on the web.)

That ought to be enough warning.  After the due date of the paper, contact the professor in the other department, explain that you counseled the student about correct citation, and volunteer to look at the final paper.

If the student took the hint, that was a teaching moment.  If not, and the student's career is "irreparably damaged," well, he did that to himself.

You can expect that the professor in the other department will watch future papers closely, which is probably all the monitoring you can do unless there are similar essays in your own department, in which case, talk to your colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perhaps the "graduate" student does not know the proper use of referring and citing others' work (especially if he is just started his studies). Hence, he is providing you with the (copied) essays to review them!
2. However, I doubt that since almost every school teaches the importance of ethics in the academic field. Keep in mind that there is a section on plagiarism in almost each syllabus and undergraduate/graduate handbook. Still I'm not familiar with this student's background, so maybe different institutes (outside Europe/ US) do not explicitly discuss plagiarism (I doubt that but maybe?)!
3. If I were you, I would confront him/her and explain that this is not the right way to write essays. After all you are a "mentor". I will explain the concept of plagiarism, citing and referencing. To be honest, I would have done this the first time I found out that some of his/her work was copied from somewhere else.

I'm not an expert on Academic penalties so maybe somebody more experienced can provide a better insight on how to address this issue (either documenting it in his/her record, or providing him/her with a second chance). Keep in mind that a graduate handbook should provide the official procedure.

Comment: Good point about not knowing. IME this is somewhat common with students from China, where the educational system heavily values memorizing and almost worshiping the words of famous leaders, philosophers, etc. On the old Imperial exams, it was expected and normal - if Confucius wrote about X, the "correct" answer to "What is X?" was to simply regurgitate verbatim what Confucius said onto your exam paper. Citation? The examiners were not ignorant - *they* knew what Confucius said, and telling them was arguably *condescending*.